# How to check header (h1, h2, h3) property of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

If I have a reference to a link in Javascript / jQuery, how can I check if it is an `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.?

Comment: How about `element.tagName`?

Comment: `false`! If it's a link, it's not a heading.

Comment: If you need to find the closest header, you can use `$(element).closest(':header')`. I'm not giving an answer as your DOM is unclear (an example always helps).

Comment: What do you mean by “a reference to a link”? And does “it” mean the reference, the link, or the destination of the link? Please provide some example(s) of what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

`element$.is('h1'); // will return true or false`

Comment: I've seen `$element` and just `element`, but I don't think I've seen `element$` before. Interesting.

Comment: Actually you can use any name you like, just try to make it easily understandable by other programmers.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that I've never seen the style of putting the `$` at the end of the name before, only at the beginning (and not putting one at all).

Comment: It's sometimes useful when you're writing some inline JS output inside the PHP view so you'll see where is the `$phpVariable` and where is your `jQueryObject$`:

`echo "var element$ = $('$selector');"`

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean *inside* a heading. You can use `:header` for that, example:

```
<h1><a href="#" id="link">link</a></h1>

var isHeading = !!$('#link').closest(':header').length;
```

Comment: I would think it's the opposite, and an anchor wrapping a heading, in which case he would use `.children()[0]`. Same concept though.

Comment: I'm not a proponent of breaking away from w3c valid markup, but wrapping text-level block elements such as headers and paragraphs is fairly commonplace.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the tag name of the element in UPPER CASE

```
$('.myClassName').get(0).tagName
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [Jquery.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

this will check if it is header type (H1,H2,H3...)

```
$('.myClassName').is(':header')
```

or

this will check if it is H1

```
$('.myClassName').is('h1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out it is a heading tag or not:

```
$(element).is('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5');
```